# Get data from Parse server ParseFile object

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

I am using Parse server to retrieve data.
I am able to do so. But within the data received, there is one additional field called `image`. When I try to access `image`, I see data inside it as `ParseFile {_name: 'some_name.png', _url: 'some_url'}`

I am not able to access `_name` and `_url`

My question is how do I access these two values?

I have tried `image._name` or `image._url` but it doesn't work.

The data is retrieved as JSON

Comment: read the docs 'creating , retreiving files' ... https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#files   using JS , you can 'fetch' the url value mentioned by the docs

Comment: I checked that, it doesn't help.

Comment: if devtools is showing you that the name 'image' w/ typeof 'ParseFile' having fields '_name' , '_url' then you need to reverse engineer the view of devTools into a referenced JS objs and properties. Normally, devtools makes apparent how u have to approach getting these JS runtime references. maybe u post a snapshot of what devtools shows to you at runtime

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to parse the retrieved JSON to JSON object.

```
var image_obj = JSON.parse(image);
image_obj._name;  //access _name by image_obj
```

Comment: No, this will not work. There has to be some method supplied from Parse server to the object that is retrieved

Answer (score 0):

The [Parse JS SDK](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.1/) has some documentation on [`Parse.File`](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.1/Parse.File.html).

Try `image.url()` and `image.name()` to access these properties